# Trouble installing and uninstalling dotnet-ef

Tags: system-error

Nobody can solve this problem in the discussion and it's been going since July.  None of us can download the application/tool we need and we all have the same problem.  Please help.

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/12921

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.  If you have this problem, you should check your `global.json` file and make sure you reduce it from 5.0.0 to 3.1.10, because the 5.0.0 version is still in beta and does not properly support dotnet-ef yet.